# WordPress theme Update

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have uploaded a theme on WordPress repository but review pointed out some issues in the theme.
I have fixed all these issues and updated my theme version. Then WordPress gave me another ticket number.

But it is not being updated or the last five days.

What is the problem and solution?

The page I need help with: https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/83941

Answer (score 1):

I looked in your ticket link:

- More than one text-domain is being used in this theme. This means the theme will not be compatible with WordPress.org language packs. The domains found are storeluda, tgmpa
- Invalid theme URI. There is no any information about the theme.
- Copy of underscores theme. Copyright (C) 2020 Automattic
- License issues, pixabay images are not allowed.

**Do you have any troubles and don't know how to solve this requirements?**
You can show us some code if you think you have done everything right.

If you don't know what to do:

In your functions.php or anywhere in your theme you are using more than one text domain. This might help: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/#text-domain Only use one text domain for your theme.

You theme uri is a public webpage where users can find out more information about the theme.
So the style.css of your theme should start with something like:

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Seventeen
Theme URI: https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyseventeen/
Author: the WordPress team
Author URI: https://wordpress.org/
Description: Twenty Seventeen brings your site to life with immersive featured images and subtle animations. With a focus on business sites, it features multiple sections on the front page as well as widgets, navigation and social menus, a logo, and more. Personalize its asymmetrical grid with a custom color scheme and showcase your multimedia content with post formats. Our default theme for 2017 works great in many languages, for any abilities, and on any device.
Version: 1.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: twentyseventeen
Tags: one-column, two-columns, right-sidebar, flexible-header, accessibility-ready, custom-colors, custom-header, custom-menu, custom-logo, editor-style, featured-images, footer-widgets, post-formats, rtl-language-support, sticky-post, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready
This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.
*/
```

Find out more: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/

You are using Underscore_s starter theme and build your theme above it. You should make this clear in your themes information.

You are also using images that are the property of someone else. Obviously you cannot use pixabay images, as they say "are not allowed". Take a look at licence free images and get a licence for the images to duplicate and sell them.